# styled components - overwrite default headings

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How can I overwrite default headings globally with styled components theme?
For colors I'm doing:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

const theme = {
  colors: {
    main: "#8563FF",
    mainLight: "#AB93FF",
    .....
  }
};

const Theme = ({ children }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
);

export default Theme;
```

and them in my component I'm getting those colors trough props

```
${props => props.theme.colors.main}
```

I would like to overwrite default headings eg. **h1** with my custom fontSize, weight..., so that when I'm using it in my component it looks like this:

```
const StyledH1 = styled.h1`
  /* additional local styling for overwritten h1 */
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.main};
  marginTop: 20px;
`;
```

On top of that, it should contains media query inside overwritten heading.
How to add overwrites to theme?

Comment: What have you tried? You mention that you want to provide a new fontSize and such, but you don't reference them at all. What stops you from just using them directly regardless of the theme (just like you are doing with `marginTop`)?

Comment: Please focus on one question instead of stacking them in one thread

Comment: And `marginTop` is a lexical error, there is no such css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`createGlobalStyle`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) and ensure that its `ThemeProvider`'s child.

> A helper function to generate a special `StyledComponent` that **handles global styles**.

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  h1 {
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.main};
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
`

// will have margin-top
styled.h1``

<ThemeProvider>
  <GlobalStyles />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Thx, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can create reset styles with **`createGlobalStyle`** and put it in the root of your project.

For example here are ***reset styles*** for all **HTML** attributes, you can import it in the **root index** file, and in the project, all default styles of HTML tags will be reset. *(styles like margins of `<p>` or `<h1>` and so on)*

You can do some modifies to set default values of some attributes, for example like the default color of `<p>`, `<h1>` or others

Examples of reset.css

`https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6`

`https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/`

Comment: thx for answer, Dennis was faster and more specific in his answer, so I accepted his